# How to change text inside modal using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using this modal:

```
 <div id="myalertbox" class="modal fade">

    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-body">

                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                You have a new notification!

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Which pops up and says "You have a new notification!". I pop it up by using this script:

```
<script>

function showAlert() {
    $("#myalertbox").modal({

        "backdrop": "static",
        "keyboard": true,
        "show": true,
    });
}

 </script>
```

I dont know how to change the text inside though? I tried with .text and .html but it doesn't work.

Comment: try this,, $('#myalertbox .modal-body').text('what text you want'); before load modal , but i think will be done by bootstrap better

Comment: thanks, works perfectly :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change text before calling the modal as

```
$("#myalertbox .modal-body").text('pass your text here');
```

Answer (score 1):

Before initiating the modal, you can change its html like:

```
$("#myalertbox .modal-body").html('pass your html here');
// It will put your html inside the div having Class .modal-body which is enclosed with a div having ID #myalertbox
```

and after that initiate its modal as usual way.

Comment: you loose the button, if you use html instead text, so use text and only change the text inside not the html content

Comment: This is not mentioned in OP question, and you can add that button again, if required.

Answer (score 1):

As the content is not nested into any tags.

It's better to use this one below.

```
 var btnHtml='< button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"> 
 &times ;< /button>';

 $('#myalertbox .modal-body').html(btnHtml +"your text here");
```